# fastest way to find maximum of list of list of integers

Tags: python, optimization

Let's say I have `a: list[list[int]] = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 7, 1]]`.

Is doing `max_a: int = max([max(tmp_list) for tmp_list in a])` the optimal way? Or is there a faster method?

I will be dealing with a list of 8 lists of around 10 elements. I will look for the max around 160,000 times every time the algorithm is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from Pythons Standard Library.

```
from itertools import chain
max_a = max(chain.from_iterable(a))
print(max_a)
```

At least on my system it's faster than the approach in the question (measured with `timeit`), but that could be different in different versions of Python. Interesting fact: If I modify the code in the question to use a generator expression it's slower.

Comment: I get a longer result (828 ns ± 12.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) vs 566 ns ± 6.38 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)) on my machine.

Comment: Actually my bad, I was timing the import too. I get 351 ns ± 3.13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) vs 559 ns ± 3.26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) without the import statement.

Comment: Could you test the original code with a generator expression? I wonder if I did something wrong or if it's really slower than building a list first.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LnpSBu7.png I do get a slower code too with a generator expression. I wonder why, it's supposed to be better because not creating a list for no reason.

Comment: I tried it with a bigger list: `a = [[i+j for i in range(10)] for j in range(10000)]`. Same behaviour.

Comment: Interestingly enough, your method does improve the time even taking account the time it takes to import the module if searching for this maximum just a handful of times.
https://i.imgur.com/z164Lno.png

Answer (score 1):

More ways/benchmarks:

```
2.30 us  2.30 us  2.31 us  chained
2.85 us  2.86 us  2.86 us  self
2.88 us  2.89 us  2.91 us  self2
2.99 us  3.00 us  3.03 us  mapmax
3.45 us  3.45 us  3.45 us  listcomp
3.46 us  3.54 us  3.54 us  genexp
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVTbauMwEH33V8xLqVy8WSeFpQRc6HcYY2RnnIi1JK8lQ0vZb8/OSLbbpIF9qwgOmjOXM2fGHt78yZrHp2E8nw/YQa@cb60ehEz3CdAZ0U@jAS1fRckPr4eanVLo7AjLDZQBWaVJwjmOaPD1Zob/JJjjtRzY8Wb8wDkycp1925NUBg@3nAO06Uara@VxlE2PYo1z2HdrEHkrKODHNtyYVhP4RHSxtWxrPmx8FDGA55DgEviUtr0ipj4Y7K4pyDKv6PddPLrJtI6gchl7Ng8vm4eQLQJngW987iqKJFnBK42KRqcHO3rKPKD0yXKT5mB19GuUw3b1U8bRX0Ra2/cEKWvcAh/wz4QR5bF5a/sVC2SSxKPzTHub58kL0y9jtU17sqpFJ@h6REFwnmbwu9jmcdlqVi5iT2kU@doeUhOWkAjMuQhvRFi8IBYNJ4MX2iKOYwuHBmTZPzf1X8JiCOPSOQxaRbcCYp0s5NjUtZEa65paJGm5xXe276Gs4EvBv8kVd2pzJhHVcKep62jpg3e67tQN1ny4IhXUyog4SdFL3RzkPk7kopcMWFgz6QbHYpum8BOCcGuyOGMRuig5ilTjy6Vu7EPvbiBCc8K3IgRsjujnToZRGS8exP3dZtfB5OAe7kB4eIAt/pq/IJzpU6Fy/1ilV3qm5/M/)):

```
def listcomp(a):
    return max([max(tmp_list) for tmp_list in a])

def genexp(a):
    return max(max(tmp_list) for tmp_list in a)

def mapmax(a):
    return max(map(max, a))

def chained(a):
    return max(chain.from_iterable(a))

def self(a):
    maxi = -1
    for b in a:
        for c in b:
            if c > maxi:
                maxi = c
    return maxi

def self2(a):
    maxi = a[0][0]
    for b in a:
        for c in b:
            if c > maxi:
                maxi = c
    return maxi

funcs = [listcomp, genexp, mapmax, chained, self, self2]

from timeit import repeat
import random
from bisect import insort
from collections import deque
from itertools import chain

tests = 100
A = [[random.choices(range(1000), k=10) for _ in range(8)]
     for _ in range(tests)]

expect = list(map(funcs[0], A))
for func in funcs:
    result = list(map(func, A))
    assert result == expect, func.__name__

times = {func: [] for func in funcs}
for _ in range(10):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for func in funcs:
        time = min(repeat(lambda: deque(map(func, A), 0), number=1)) / tests
        insort(times[func], time)
for func in sorted(funcs, key=times.get):
    print(*('%.2f us ' % (t * 1e6) for t in times[func][:3]), func.__name__)
```

Comment: Thank you! Still surprised that a list comprehension does better than a generator expression but eh.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows All that switching between the generator iterator and its consumer takes time, too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Isn't the list comprehension using the generator iterator as well, but just storing it in a list? I assume no, but I'm wondering where the difference is then.

Comment: No, list comprehension is not using a generator iterator. You can [disassemble](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCEls5iLC0joAbGGenSFQlp@kUKFQmaeQkVxrLomV0FRZl6JhrquuoKWgrm5JkKpBopSTXXN//8B) to see the differences.

Comment: Wow, I was not aware disassembling was something that existed. Thank you for all the insights.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)
Now, the thing about optimization is that it can be VERY input-reliant. Even if in theory some method is better for big input sizes, the cost of spinning up the environment to run it might be more than the benefit gained from using more complex methods. Below is a sample code I created for testing different algorithms.

When running with data sizes you provided, it seems simple double max is best for the job, while working with numpy arrays is always slower. Where I see some possiblity for performance gain is numba's JIT combined with np.array. It is slower at your sample sizes, but when the problem grows it becomes more and more efficient. On top of it, subsequent calls are incredibly more efficient because they are already compiled, beating all other options by several orders of magnitude.

As you can see, the algorithms cannot be compared in the void if you hope to gain actual performance gain, and should be selected and tested case by case on an actual working data.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from itertools import chain
n, m = 8, 10
ls = [[random.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]

k = 160000
from functools import wraps
from time import time

def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        ts = time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time()
        print(f"func:{f.__name__} took {te-ts}s, {result=}")
        return result
    return wrap

@timing
def test1(k, ls):
    for i in range(k):
        max(max(ls))
    return max(max(ls))

npls = np.array(ls)

@timing
def test2(k, npls):
    for i in range(k):
        npls.max()
    return npls.max()

@timing
@njit
def test3(k, npls):
    for i in range(k-1):
        npls.max()
    return npls.max()
    
@timing
def test4(k, ls):
    for i in range(k):
        max(chain.from_iterable(ls))
    return max(chain.from_iterable(ls))

test1(k, ls)
test2(k, npls)
test3(k, npls)
test4(k, ls)

ls = [[random.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
npls = np.array(ls)

test3(k, npls)
```

Comment: Where are the results?

Comment: You switched the numbers for n and m.

Comment: You're not testing with integers.

Comment: `test1` is wrong (and most of the time you can see that in your results).